# CTE Query copy value if exists into an existing table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I got the following query:

```
WITH table_data AS (
             SELECT UNNEST(array['Small Bus', 'Window', 'Test 1']) AS description,
                    UNNEST(array['1dfsdf4', 'QSF-312', 'EXD-TUH']) AS code,
                    UNNEST(array[NOW(), NOW(), NOW()]) AS updated,
                    UNNEST(array[NOW(), NOW(), NOW()]) AS created,
                    UNNEST(array[0.15, 350.0, 5.0]) AS sales_price,
                    UNNEST(array[0.51, 550.0, 10.0]) AS price,
                    UNNEST(array['Tax0', 'cdc', '54289hijlj']) AS code_p,
                    UNNEST(array['242', 'ded', 'fjDIashdukah']) AS sales_c
           ),
        parts_inserted AS (
         INSERT INTO parts (description, item_code, created, updated, sale_p,
                                    price, code_p_id, s_id_code)
         SELECT table_data.description, table_data.code, table_data.created, table_data.updated,
                table_data.sales_price, table_data.price, rates_p.id, rates_c.id
           FROM table_data
           LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_p
              ON table_data.code_p = rates_p.code
           LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_c
              ON table_data.sales_c = rates_c.code
          JOIN parts p ON p.item_code = table_data.code
          WHERE p.company_id = 65312322
         RETURNING *
       )
       SELECT * FROM parts_inserted;
```

The query selects the data ( `WITH table_data AS...` ) and inserts it into the parts table.

Table parts:

```
CREATE TABLE
    parts
    (
        id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('p_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
        company_id INTEGER,
        item_code CHARACTER VARYING,
        price DOUBLE PRECISION,
        code_p_id INTEGER,
        sale_p DOUBLE PRECISION,
        s_id_code INTEGER,
        profit DOUBLE PRECISION,
        margin DOUBLE PRECISION,
        created TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        updated TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        taxable BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
        origin CHARACTER VARYING,
        origin_id CHARACTER VARYING,
        description TEXT,
        created_by_id INTEGER,
        name CHARACTER VARYING,
        tsv TSVECTOR
    );
```

- If `code_p` exists on the rates table, the query must insert the `rates.id` into `parts.p_code_id`
- If `sales_c` exists on the rates table, the query must insert the `rates.id` into `parts.s_id_code`
- If none of them exists, the `p_code_id` and `s_id_code` must be blank.

Table rates:

```
CREATE TABLE
    rates
    (
        id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('r_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
        company_id INTEGER,
        name CHARACTER VARYING,
        rate DOUBLE PRECISION,
        created TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        updated TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        type CHARACTER VARYING,
        origin CHARACTER VARYING,
        origin_id CHARACTER VARYING,
        code CHARACTER VARYING,
        is_payable BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
        description CHARACTER VARYING,
        active BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
        has_component BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
    );
```

- Currently only valid code_p and sales_c row gets inserted, if  `code_p/sales_c` exists: 
  ( 
  `LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_p
            ON table_data.code_p = rates_p.code
         LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_c
            ON table_data.sales_c = rates_c.code`
  ) it is inserted into `parts` table.
- If `code_p` or `sales_c` does not matches with the `rates` table, the row must be inserted with blank(**NULL**) `code_p/sales_c`... and this is not happening.

**What should the query do?**

if `code_p` or `sales_c` matches with the `rates` table:

```
LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_p
              ON table_data.code_p = rates_p.code
           LEFT JOIN rates AS rates_c
              ON table_data.sales_c = rates_c.code
```

the `parts.code_p_id` and `parts.s_id_code` columns must be updated with the `rates.id` value.

if `code_p` or `sales_c` doesn't match with the `rates` table, the `parts.code_p_id` and `parts.s_id_code` columns must be blank/null.

**Question:**

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are the fields `purchase_code_id` and `sale_code_id`? Perhaps you should include your DDL and clarify the question.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the sample data in the first CTE can be done simpler using the `values` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9657 In fact: I think it is not guaranteed that all `unnest()` calls return the rows in the same order (although in reality I don't think it will ever happen in a different order)

Comment: That query seems to do what you want. How is it not working for you? What does it do that you don't want, or doesn't do that you need?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: After several edits your question still does not add up. You reference `purchase_code`, but it's nowhere in your question. Please present a coherent question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Unnesting in parallel is actually guaranteed if all arrays have the same number of elements. But there are superior alternatives in modern Postgres. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - It was an error of writing... have edited the question again and updated the wrong fields. Please have a look

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: ah, thanks. But I still find the `values (..)` clause more readable ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It certainly is.

Comment: @PatrickB.: You are still mixing terms. `code_p_id`, `p_code_id`? A sentence like `only valid code_p and sales_c row gets inserted` does not make any sense to people who don't know what "valid" is supposed to mean. And "empty" does not make any sense for an integer values. Maybe you should work with something more fault-tolerant than databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have so far can be rewritten to this 100 % equivalent query:

```
INSERT INTO parts
        (description, item_code, created,   updated,   sale_p     ,   price, code_p_id, s_id_code)
SELECT t.description, t.code , t.created, t.updated, t.sales_price, t.price, rp.id    , rc.id
FROM  (
   VALUES 
     ('Small Bus', '1dfsdf4', now(), now(), 0.15 , 0.51 , 'Tax0'      , '242')
   , ('Window'   , 'QSF-312', now(), now(), 350.0, 550.0, 'cdc'       , 'ded')
   , ('Test 1'   , 'EXD-TUH', now(), now(), 5.0  , 10.0 , '54289hijlj', 'fjDIashdukah')
   ) t(description, code, updated, created, sales_price, price, code_p, sales_c)
JOIN   parts       p ON pa.item_code = t.code  -- why?
LEFT   JOIN rates rp ON rp.code      = t.code_p
LEFT   JOIN rates rc ON rc.code      = t.sales_c
WHERE  p.company_id = 65312322                 -- why?
RETURNING *;
```

The query already inserts NULL into `code_p_id` and `s_id_code` respectively if no matching row in `rates` is found.

You don't *need* CTEs here.
Be aware that the `RETURNING` clause returns actual resulting values of new rows *after* applying any rules or triggers there might be.

You description is still unclear.
The join to `parts` seems highly suspicious. `parts.company_id` is not defined `UNIQUE`, the join will probably multiply rows. I seriously doubt that's intended.

You might really mean to `UPDATE` selected rows in table `parts`, not `INSERT` new rows ...

Comment: I changed the `JOIN PARTS` to: `JOIN PARTS p ON p.company_id = rp.company_id`.. Also took off the `WHERE` and it's working as expected.